# Timer component not stopping

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, click

I'm working with a Winforms app and I'm tyring to make a label "glide" up when a user clicks on it. To do this, I've created a click event that starts a timer, which then gradually moves the label up the form. I then have a counter that I increment, and when the counter reaches a certain position, the timer should stop. The timer is not stopping, however. I've deliberately set the counter limit to 2 for testing purposes, but the label continues to fly off the form. Here is the code:

```
private void DrawerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        newsLabel.Top -= 10;
        counter++;
        if (counter == 2)
            drawerTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void News_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawerTimer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: In addidtion to the error, writng `if (counter >= 2)` is called defensive programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int counter = 0; // here you are setting it 0
newsLabel.Top -= 10;
counter++; // here you are incrementing it by 1
if (counter == 2) // here you are checking for 2, its never going to get there
   drawerTimer.Stop();
```

More than likely you will want to do something like this

```
private int _counter; // instance field, field to remember your count

private void DrawerTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newsLabel.Top -= 10;
    counter++; // increment it every tick
    if (counter == 2)
        drawerTimer.Stop();
}

private void News_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _counter = 0; // set to zero when start
    drawerTimer.Start();
}
```